# How to return a special value to parent program?

Tags: c++

I have a program A that invoke another one B to do something.  I'd like to have B to send a signal or something  whenever it reaches a location so that A knows.  Currently I am using a seemingly stupid approach:  I have B to print "REACHED"  , and then in A I capture all output of B and scan for the string "REACHED" (see code below).  What are some other alternatives ? Thanks,

```
//B, at the desired location
printf("REACHED");

//A
FILE *fin = popen("./B","r");                                                                                                                                                       

while(fgets(buff,sizeof(buff),fin)){
  string res(buff);
  if (res.find("REACH") != string::npos){  //naive way 
    //got it    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Shared memory
- Signals
- Write to a file (e.g. a pipe, or a network connection)
- Use an existing inter-process communication (IPC) library